# How to create a winform with buttons that will never attract keyboard focus

Tags: winforms, button, keyboard, focus

I have a few textboxes on my winform. I have a few buttons on it too. Now when I am typing on one such textbox and clicks a button, then the input focus is lost from the textbox and the button gets the input keyboard focus. That is, the cursor is lost from the textbox the moment we click the button. I dont want this behavior. I want my textbox to retain the cursor within even when I click the button. 
The real situation is that I am having textbox and numeric buttons to be only used from touchscreen.

Answer (score 10):

Try creating your own button control that inherits from the standard one but turns off the `Selectable` style:

```
public class ButtonEx : Button {
  public ButtonEx() {
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
  }
}
```

Comment: I had a case with a TabControl, whoms tabs should never be focusable. `TabStop = False` would not work, but your solution worked.

Answer (score 4):

In your button click event handler(s), explicitly set focus to **some other control**. Pick any control that you believe would be sensible to gain focus after the button is pressed. For example, set focus to a TextBox, using code like this:

```
textBox1.Focus();
```

This will prevent your button from gaining focus when a button is clicked.

In addition, set your button's [`TabStop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dst5y6fs) property to false.

The other answers suggesting you set the [`CanFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.canfocus.aspx) property to false won't work because that property is read-only for buttons.

Comment: That's good to know. Is there a ways to prevent the flicker and make the solution work with more than 1 TextBox?

Comment: what if there were more than two textboxes?

Comment: @r.hamd - you misunderstand the answer. In each **button** click handler, you set focus to **some other control**. Use any control that it would make sense to have focus next. A logical choice is to set focus to **some text box** that is *after* the button. Visually this would look the same is if someone "tabbed" to that text box, to make it the active input.  Another good alternative is to set focus to the **first text box** on the form. [Editing answer to clarify this.]

Comment: Note that setting button's [TabStop] property to `false`, while it does match OP's request to have button "never attract keyboard focus", would make the form **unusable by keyboard-only users**. This is not needed on a touchscreen, and if a keyboard might be attached, this should not be done, as it violates **accessibility standards**. I recommend *not* doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You could set focus to the text box on buttons click event handler like this:

```
private void Button_Click(...)
{
    FocusTextBox();
    // Do things...
}

private void FocusTextBox()
{
    textBox.Focus();
}
```

Comment: what if there were more than two textboxes?

Answer (score 0):

Create custom `Button` class with `Focusable` property, set `Focusable` to `false`

```
public class ButtonEx : Button
{
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool Focusable
    {
        get { return GetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable); }
        set { SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, value); }
    }
}
```