# Prevent focus on Control

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm working on a project where I have an input with validation.
Next to it there are a set of buttons which you can press. When you focus the input the buttons will be shown. But when you click on 1 of the buttons the focus of the input is gone and the validation will start and the buttons will be hidden.

What I want is that the input focus is not lost, at any time.

**Is it possible to not activate/focus the buttons when you click on them or is it possible to force focus on the input without losing it?**

I have tried this on the Control, but seems to be only working on a form:

```
Const WS_EX_NOACTIVATE As Integer = &H8000000
Const WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW As Integer = &H80

Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams As CreateParams
    Get
        Dim ret As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        ret.ExStyle = ret.ExStyle Or WS_EX_NOACTIVATE Or WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW
        Return ret
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: [How to stop pressing button using keyboard keys like “Spacebar or Enter”. C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823525/how-to-stop-pressing-button-using-keyboard-keys-like-spacebar-or-enter-c-shar/32825190#32825190), [How to create a winform with buttons that will never attract keyboard focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077945/how-to-create-a-winform-with-buttons-that-will-never-attract-keyboard-focus). Setting `ControlStyles.Selectable` to `false` also prevents getting focus when clicked with a mouse.

Comment: Set the buttons' CausesValidation property to False.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your custom button and make it non-selectable:

```
Public Class MyButton
    Inherits Button

    Public Sub New()
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, False)
    End Sub

End Class
```

If you don't want to create custom control, set `CausesValidation = False` for your normal button and it will get focus, but doesn't cause validation.

Answer (score 0):

Set the [`TabStop` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabstop(v=vs.110).aspx) of the buttons to false.

By setting this to false you'll stop them receiving focus when the user tabs, but they'll still be clickable.