# Access button only by mouse click (c#)

Tags: c#, button, click, mouse

I'm currently working on a simple snake game for a school project and everything is working like a charm, except the "Select Speed" property I'm trying to make.

In the game the snake has a standard speed, but if you click a button, the speed should change to the speed you selected. This part I am pretty sure I got going.

When I start up the game to try it, the arrow keys can only be used to operate the buttons, and since the snake is controlled by the arrow keys, that is a big problem. When I disables the buttons, the game works exactly like it is supposed to.

How can I limit the button of the buttons in such a way, that the buttons can only be accessed by mouse click and my arrow keys don't get stuck on them?

Hope my question makes sense to you.

Thanks in advance!

---

Comment: Isn't that default behaviour of buttons? Being able to click them by mouse but not with arrow keys?

Comment: Your question is not clear. A friendly Tip: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before asking question.

Comment: look at this question, it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077945/how-to-create-a-winform-with-buttons-that-will-never-attract-keyboard-focus